# Center Text Relative to the Flex-Container's vertical axis, not the Flex-Item it belongs to

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to setup a header for an application that I am currently struggling with centering the text for. Essentially, I want to center the text in first Flex Item to the containers cross-axis (not the flex-items center), however, I am not sure what is the correct way to do so with even number of items.

[image]

[image]

As a hack I have currently added a placeholder div to the left and set it as hidden, however, I am curious to see if there is a more obvious and elegant way to do this.

Thanks!

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #74c0c5;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 2px lightgrey;
}

.child-title {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  flex: 2;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
    
.arrow {
  padding: 0 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>

<div class="parent-flex">
    <span class="child-title">Text Here 123</span>
    <div>
        <i class='fas fa-angle-right arrow' style='font-size:42px;color:white'></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh I think the picture makes it look like that'd be a solution, but I want to center the text to the parents width. Right align wont work for the example I provided.

Comment: Not possible. The content of the flex-child element is not affect by the layout of the parent flex-container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.parent-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #74c0c5;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px 2px lightgrey;
}

.child-title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.parent-flex div{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.arrow {
  padding: 0 20px;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<div class="parent-flex">
    <span class="child-title">Text Here 123</span>
    <div>
        <i class='fas fa-angle-right arrow' style='font-size:42px;color:white'></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow that is pretty smart thinking Osman! Not sure what the purpose of the `.parent-flex div {}` is but looks good otherwise. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is to align the arrow vertically. `.arrow{vertical-align:center}` does nor align the arrow :) You are welcome, and thank you so much for your good words :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that, is to make the arrow's position absolute, and the child-title width's 100% so that the title would be centered as wanted.

But you risk having the arrow over the text in case you have a long title.